# motor to turn a screw to move a lever

Tags: actuator

Where I can buy an actuator that consists of a motor that turns a screw that moves a rod?

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for a [linear actuator](https://www.google.ca/search?espv=2&q=linear+actuator&oq=linear+actuator&gs_l=serp.3..0i67k1j0l9.1514.4134.0.4407.15.10.0.5.5.0.137.832.8j2.10.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.15.856...35i39k1j0i131k1j0i20k1j0i46i67k1j46i67k1.JKWcwZlpNdU).

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, SoftwareFramework. As it stands, it's not clear what your goal is. Do you want the rod to *translate* (slide along its longitudinal axis) or do you want the rod to *rotate*? Can you explain the gear/screw setup? Are you trying to look for a device that can't be back-driven? I'm going to put the question on hold to give you the opportunity to *edit your question* to include details of what you're looking for because right now it seems that people are guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a worm drive (pictured below)?
[image: Worm Drive]

If so there are plenty of places to get one depending on your needs, I have linked some below:

- From [Vex](http://www.vexrobotics.com/gears.html)
- From [Andymark](http://www.andymark.com/product-p/am-0917.htm)
- Plenty of people on [Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/worm-gear-set)
- From [Tetrix](http://www.pitsco.com/TETRIX_Worm_Gear_Box)

And many others, if you could tell us more about what you want to do we could be more helpful.